# Get Message Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=<home_dir>/.pm2 always

Tags: amazon-ec2, pm2

On ec-2 instance whenever I execute pm2 I get the message...

```
Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=<home_dir>/.pm2
```

This occurs with `pm2 info`, `pm2 list`, `pm2 -h` etc.

A bare `pm2` will show help.

I can get more response from `sudo -i`.

It seems something is stopping PM2 from demonising when non-sudo.

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem in my case:

```
pm2 delete 0
```

I had been looking at other answers like reinstalling pm2, installing a previous version, permission issues, and none of them worked or applied to my case.

I'm not positive but I think I had a buggy process that was blocking the spawn. I had used pm2 a couple of days prior when I first logged into my server but I had been running an app that kept crashing and I tried to listen on port 80 and got permission errors.
Ubuntu 18 server machine, Node 12.14.1, NPM 6.13.4, PM2 4.2.3

Answer (score 1):

This usually means that `pm2` is running under PID that differs from the one in your `.pm2/pm2.pid`

To exit from this situation try one of these:

`pm2 kill`

or

`ps aux | grep pm2` and then `kill -9 PID` found in `PM2 vX.X.X: God Daemon`

if none of the above help:

```
pkill node && \
pm2 delete all && \
pm2 flush && \
kill -9 $(head -n 1 /home/$USER/.pm2/pm2.pid) && \
rm -rf /home/$USER/.pm2
```

After that run `pm2 ls` or whatever `pm2` command you want. That should daemonize `pm2` again with the correct PID in `.pm2/pm2.pid`

**EDIT**

Another possible reason could be any error during the `pm2` init, so if the above doesn't work for you check `.pm2/pm2.log` for any errors and fix them

Answer (score 0):

Hi I fixed this by using an older version of pm2

```
npm uninstall -g pm2
npm install -g pm2@3.2.2
```

Answer (score -1):

I just set -

```
 pm2_home=C:\Users\<Admin/Your Account>\.pm2
```

in environment variables.

And then

restart your the PC / server.